# this government never of itself furthered any enterprise

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> It has not the vitality and force of a single living man; for a single
>   man can bend it to his will. It is a sort of wooden gun to the people
>   themselves. But it is not the less necessary for this; for the people
>   must have some complicated machinery or other, and hear its din, to
>   satisfy that idea of government which they have. Governments show thus
>   how successfully men can be imposed on, even impose on themselves, for
>   their own advantage. It is excellent, we must all allow. **Yet this
>   government never of itself furthered any enterprise, but *by* the
>   alacrity *with* which it got out of its way**.

1. Can I reorder it as "Yet this government never furthered any enterprise [of itself], but [furthered the enterprise] by the alacrity, with [the alacrity] it got out of its way"?
2. What does "alacrity" mean here? and "by the alacrity"?

Comment: The government never took steps to further an enterprise except by quickly stepping aside so as not to impede the progress of that enterprise.  **never of itself** modifies "the government furthered". Never of itself did the government further any enterprise...

Comment: by the alacrity with which it [the govt] got out of its [the enterprise's] way.  That prepositional phrase also modifies "the government furthered an enterprise".

Comment: The pattern: X never did Y except by doing Z.    X never did Y but by doing Z. (*but* is a synonym of *except* there)

Comment: Consider: He helped by bringing the paint and brushes.  The *by*-phrase describes the manner of his helping.   *He never helped with the work except by bringing the paint and brushes.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> He ate the food *quickly*, and by that, I knew he was very hungry.
>
> He ate the food *with great speed*, and by that, I knew he was very
>   hungry.

**with great speed**  is a prepositional phrase with a noun-phrase as the object of *with*.  It means "quickly" and works like an adverb to modify "he ate the food". It gives info about the manner of the eating of the food.

The *by*-phrase modifies the main clause; it expresses how I knew, the means by which I knew. When we want to make that noun-phrase "great speed" the object of **by** we must relocate **with** and use a relative:

> I knew he was very hungry by *the great speed with which* he ate the
>   food.
>
> By the great speed with which he ate the food, I knew he was very hungry.